# Pre select an item in select box in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I want to make an item is pre selected in my selectbox,how it is possible in angularjs
my code is given below

```
<select  ng-model="selectedClient"  ng-init="client.id == 117" ng-options="client.name for client in 
                         clients" class="form-control"></select>
```

I want to make item 117 as preselected but it is not working.

Comment: it should be `ng-options="client.id as client.name for client in 
                         clients"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not think AngularJS models as only values or ids if you have Arrays filled up objects. You have to approach it as object in this situation.

If you have an array like this:

```
var clients = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Client 1",
    active: false
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Client 2",
    active: false
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Client 3",
    active: false
}];
```

You can preselect one of them like below:

```
$scope.selectedClient = clients[0];
```

Keep in mind that the selectedClient is an object.

Comment: here clients[0] means first item from clients,rite? In my case I am not sure in which item should be select? I have 'Id' value,can I select by using id value?

Comment: You have to find proper object which has the **id** value that you have. I use **findWhere**  method of the http://underscorejs.org for my that like needs. For example: `$scope.selectedClient = _.findWhere(clients, {id: 1});`

Comment: returning undefined :(

Answer (score 1):

You assign the selected item to the model object `selectedClient`

```
$scope.selectedClient = $scope.clients[1]
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c069Lnn8/)

Comment: I want to select based on condition

Comment: @ShihabudheenMuhammed yes... based on the condition you assign the object to `selectedClient`

Comment: Thank you for the answer,now it is working but the problem is now value of selectedClient is integer rather than object. I want to object there.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your mark up should look like below.

**HTML**

```
<select  ng-model="selectedClient" ng-options="client.id as client.name for client in clients" 
class="form-control" ng-init="selectedClient = 117"></select>
```

Comment: when using `client_id as` it returns client_id,I want to client object,how it is possible?